Style Dictionary - how to export interconnected design tokens?
I would like to ask for advice and help with configuring and formatting Style Dictionary.
Since my design tokens are structured into three levels – primitive, semantic, and specific – I would like, after compiling the design tokens for different operating systems, to ensure that they remain interconnected, as they are in the original JSON file that I provide as a reference to Style Dictionary.
Unfortunately, the result is that both the primitive, semantic, and specific tokens are receiving primitive values.
I tried chatting with GPT and he advised me to create an additional build.js file in which to describe the necessary transformations and formatting, but as soon as I tried to build the project through it, it gave errors.
This is my reference JSON file:
{
  "token": {
    "spacer": {
      "value": "12px",
      "type": "dimension"
    },
    "gap": {
      "value": "{token.spacer}",
      "type": "dimension"
    },
    "button-gap": {
      "value": "{token.gap}",
      "type": "dimension"
    }
  }
}

and this is the config file:
{
    "source": ["tokens/**/*.json"],
    "platforms": {
      "web": {
        "transformGroup": "scss",
        "buildPath": "build/web/",
        "files": [
          {
            "destination": "variables.scss",
            "format": "scss/variables"
          }
        ]
      },
      "ios": {
        "transformGroup": "ios",
        "buildPath": "build/ios/",
        "files": [
          {
            "destination": "tokens.h",
            "format": "ios/macros"
          }
        ]
      },
      "android": {
        "transformGroup": "android",
        "buildPath": "build/android/",
        "files": [
          {
            "destination": "tokens.xml",
            "format": "android/resources"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  

The result is:
Web:
$token-spacer: 12px;
$token-gap: 12px;
$token-button-gap: 12px;

Android:
<resources>
  <dimen name="token_spacer">192.00dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="token_gap">192.00dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="token_button_gap">192.00dp</dimen>
</resources>

iOS:
#define TokenSpacer 192.00f
#define TokenGap 192.00f
#define TokenButtonGap 192.00f

As you can see all export results receive the primitive value instead of getting the referenced token.
Thank you very much in advance!

Solved partially,
it was the
"outputReferences": true - option
that I have missed!
Now it works for both web and android, but ios still get all primitive values.
"files": [
{
"options": {
"outputReferences": true
}
}
]
